# truncate file SECURELY (php)

Tags: php, file, filesystems, truncate, erase

- Have a file with a **sensitive data**.
- Then read some stuff from the end, e.g. last 1000 bytes.
- Then truncate off this stuff. But not just as easily - I want this data to be **never recovered** - so truncate them securely. I mean there won't left any byte from those once read.
- An option is to **alter them all to null-bytes**. But how?

In PHP a solution that rises in my head instantly:

```
$offset = filesize($file) - 1000;
$h = fopen($file, 'r+b');
// read my data

fseek($h, $offset);
fwrite($h, str_repeat("\x00", 1000), 1000);
fclose($h);

$h = fopen($file, 'cb');
ftruncate($h, $offset);
fclose($h);
```

- QI.: Will solution **alter exactly** those **bytes** present in a file?
- QII.: Is double open-close execution necessary? (not sure if `fread` immediately writes data or it's cached & written after resource pointer close).

*Might be Q more 'bout filesystem rather than programming. I use NTFS (Win), but I'd like my app been cross-platform.*

Know 'bout `shred` ([Secure delete with PHP 5.3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011809/secure-delete-with-php-5-3-x#answer-11011859)), but not solution in my case.

Comment: What file system are you using? The answer will depend on the details of the file system you're using.

Comment: I use NTFS (Win), but I'd like my app been cross-platform. (*edited in Q*)